# Find unused protobuf fields in a project

Tags: go

Working on a big legacy project with multiple Protobuf messages and many fields.

Trying to see if it is possible to programmatically find unused proto fields throughout the project. Lets assume these Messages are used strictly in this one codebase written in Go.

Any suggestion?

Comment: “Go/ast” would be your friend here.  I assume the question is a bit more nuanced, though. You’re looking for fields that are not read – writes would not be “use” in your definition?

Comment: @TiN Your requirement is interesting. May be ask you what your next steps you want to do after finding the list of of unused fields.

Comment: i would delete a field from the proto def, regen, recompile. If it fails, the field should not be removed, otherwise, it might be deleted. Error mssages from the compiler will help ensuring the reason. Some coding will help automatize this. Obvisouly go/ast is oyur friend, but unless you are experienced to it, it is an abrupt learning.

Comment: @Mitch that is good question, writes happens at some specific package which needs too be excluded. I'll try go/ast.
mh-cbon will try delete, regen, recompile as 2nd option. Thanks!